# Lightweight C# Persistent Key-value store?

Tags: c#

I'm building a small internal app that runs on webforms and need a lightweight way to store key/value pairs for settings. The keys and values would both be strings, the values being of unknown length and possibly containing formatting characters. What's the simplest thing that could possibly work for this? I had considered using SQL to store it, but that just seems silly. All I need are the following features:
1) Be able to tell if a key exists
2) Be able to retrieve a value by key
3) Be able to set a value by key

Really, I could get by with simply persisting a Dictionary to disk, but I'm not sure how to cleanly do it in a way that avoids issues with special characters (like carriage returns, commas, etc.).

Anybody have a particularly lazy way to do this?

Edit: The data items in question will be loaded into a property grid, not into individual winforms controls, so I don't think I'll be able to use the PropertyBinding infrastructure for this.

Edit: I forgot to add that I'll need to be able to add brand new keys at runtime. The full set of keys won't be known at design time.

Comment: Why would using SQL be silly? Also, really *any* type of data store can do this. Which is more appropriate depends a lot on your use case. Things that matter are for example if you need to change the values at run-time, if you need concurrency etc.

Comment: I was thinking that SQL would be silly just because it is overkill. It just seems like way more effort than is needed. I might be able to get by just saving that dictionary to disk and moving on with life.

Answer (score 3):

Try to use the built in Settings system: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa730869.aspx

Answer (score 1):

If your application already uses a database, I would just use that instead of adding another technology to the mix.

Comment: It doesn't currently use a database (it currently doesn't persist anything - it's just a utility).

Comment: AppSettings? If that's not enough, XML or Sqlite might do it.